# I want to make a clever handing out of the role HOTS

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make a clever handing out of the role HOTS, if the user in the "playing" is "Heroes of the Storm", but did not succeed, although the bot is not showing error what to do?

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    serverchannel = 'channel_id'
    fileLFG = '{0}(LFG).txt'.format(before.id)
    if os.path.exists(fileLFG):
        with open(fileLFG, "r") as readFile:
            LFG = int(readFile.read())
    else:
        with open(fileLFG, "w") as writeFile:
            writeFile.write(str(0))
    if after.game == 'Heroes of the Storm' and LFG == 1:
    await client.add_roles(after, roleHOTS)
```

Comment: Does the LFG file already exist?  Does it get written? If it has to be written, you never give `LFG` a value. What is the LFG file for?

Comment: The bot automatically creates this file and makes it equal to 0

Comment: It is for the automatic handing out of the roles, if the user write !lfg he will NOT be granted the role of HOTS